# Space before and after a slash

Tags: punctuation

In English, a space is added before and after a slash when the slash is used to separate two phrases made of more than one word.

> I will call you when the president/secretary will ask for you.

> I will call you when the President / Secretary of state will ask for you.

Is there any rule for Italian?

I would rather not use any space, but I am not sure that is the correct way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually in Italian, you don't use any space before punctuation but only after (with some exceptions).
In the case of a slash, if it divides two single words it is used without space as "e/o" or "il/la".
If slash is used to divide two sentences, you'd better use the space as in your second example, so it is the same as in English.